# How can I number my answers to questions when my answers are just figures?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, enumerate

I have a homework assignment and the answers consist of just figures. Every time I try to use enumerate or section, the numbers show up before the figures (so it will show 1. 2. and then show all my figures).

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item{}
             \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1barchart.png}\\
                \caption{Bar chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1piechart.png}\\
                \caption{Pie chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.}
            \end{figure}
         \item{}
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1raquetbar.png}\\
                \caption{Bar chart of racquet brands for tennis club. n=15.}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1raquetpie.png}\\
                \caption{Pie chart of racquet brands for tennis club. n=15.}
            \end{figure} 
        \item{}
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1treehistogram.png}\\
                \caption{Histogram of tree heights. n=16.}
            \end{figure}
    \end{enumerate}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: One solution is to not use figures or captions, but to format them them same as any other "answer".  Another is to use `\setcounter{figure}` to the desired value, and possibly redefine \thefigure.  If you want a detailed solution, we will need a full MWE, and in this case showing normal answers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the graphics in a floating `figure` environments if you don't want them to float.   Just try something like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Bar chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1barchart.png}
        \end{center}
    \item Pie chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1piechart.png}
        \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
```

NB not compiled...

Comment: But that seems to center \item. I want it to be set up as 1. Figure (and underneath that I want the caption Figure 1. caption)

Comment: ... then look at the `captionof` package that lets you make fake captions outside figure environments.   <opinion> You are a victim of the most common problem in Latex, and the feeblest bit of design -- the muddling up of figures and floats... </opinion>

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the `figure` environment allows tex to "float" the figure to where it thinks is best.  If you don't want it to float, then you don't want the `figure` environment.  Unfortunately, without the `figure` environment, figures can't have captions.  The solution is to use the `caption` package and its `\captionof` and `captionsetup` commands.  The only remaining problem is that enumerate's numbering may not be place where you want, which may involve some finagling.  Your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % just to get them all on one page

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item
  \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1barchart.png}\\
   \captionof{figure}{Bar chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.  Note (1.) is too low.}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1piechart.png}\\
   \captionof{figure}{Pie chart of Professor rank data from a private institution. n=230.}
  \end{center}
 \item\mbox{}\\[-3\baselineskip]
  \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1raquetbar.png}\\
   \captionof{figure}{Bar chart of racquet brands for tennis club. n=15.  (2.) moved with baselineskip.}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1raquetpie.png}\\
   \captionof{figure}{Pie chart of racquet brands for tennis club. n=15.}
  \end{center}
 \item
  \begin{center}
   \raisebox{-.9\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.60]{hw1treehistogram.png}}\\
   \captionof{figure}{Histogram of tree heights. n=16.  (3.) moved with raisebox.}
  \end{center}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]